# determining the time complexity for particular code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to determine complexity for second_max function but how do i do it, how to determine time complexity for my code and for any other code

```
from random import randint
import sys
from bigO import BigO

def r_array(r_i= 0,r_e = 100,step=10):
    return [randint(r_i, r_e) for i in range(r_i, r_e, step)]

def second_max(arr):
    n_max = -sys.maxsize
    n_s_max = -sys.maxsize

    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] > n_max:
                n_s_max = n_max
                n_max = arr[i]
            elif (arr[i] < n_max and arr[i] > n_s_max):
                n_s_max = arr[i]

    return n_s_max

_lib = BigO()
cmplx = _lib.test(second_max, "")

array = r_array(step=20)
print(f"original array: {array}")
second_large_num = second_max(array)
print(second_large_num)
```

I consider my code(second_max) has o(n) complexity but not sure.

i tried bigO module but it returns

```
for i in range(len(array) - 1):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the bigO python module can only *estimate* the time complexity. It is theoretically impossible for a program to "calculate" the time complexity of all possible algorithms. This is similar to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

So don't rely on that module for finding out the time complexity. There is no method for determining the time complexity that will always work. For some complex, known algorithms there is even no proof yet of what their time complexity is.

A second thing to consider is what  is. In your example it seems that the *size of the list* is . Sometimes though the (maximum) size of the numbers themselves in the list could be taken into account as well, as the comparison of two numbers (for instance) takes time that is dependent on the (memory) size of the numbers, certainly when Python has unrestricted integer sizes (see also [Computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)). Here I will assume the size of the numbers is not an aspect of , and all comparison operations may be considered to run in O(1) time complexity.

For this particular piece of code there is a simple analysis we can make: there is just one loop that visits each member of the `arr` list, and each operation in the body of the loop has a constant time complexity (none of these operations depend on the size of the list):

```py
       if arr[i] > n_max:
            n_s_max = n_max
            n_max = arr[i]
        elif (arr[i] < n_max and arr[i] > n_s_max):
            n_s_max = arr[i]
```

All of the above lines, if they get executed, have O(1) time complexity (again, with the above-mentioned assumptions). Also the loop condition and the initialisation before the loop have constant time complexity.

That means the overal time complexity is O().

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `n` in `O(n)` to mean the array length `len(arr)`, being the only plausible interpretation.

> I consider my code(second_max) has o(n) complexity but not sure.

Can it be less than `O(n)`? No, you have a loop that is executed `n` times:

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
```

Can it be more than `O(n)`? No:

- Outside the loop, you have only simple assignments, each being `O(1)`, executed 1 time, resulting in `O(1)` - we can ignore that, as we already have an `O(n)` part.
- Inside the loop, you have only only simple comparisons, conditionals, and assignments, each being `O(1)`, executed at most `n` times. This results in `O(n)`.

So, overall it's `O(n)`.